# Nginx - Node.js error with upstream

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

Have a Frontend server which accesses a backend api all written in node.js.
Currently have Nginx with Phusion Passenger configured to launch the node app
Everything has been running fine when all environments (dev.qa.prod) experienced this similar issue which crashed our Frontend servers.  Restarting Nginx allowed the application to work.

The Errors look like this

```
[error] 25833#0: *14050 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.0.183, server: 54.148.10.11, request: "POST /api/course/54e113e8d98e579c1a790bbd/step/54e113e8d98e579c1a790bbe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://54.201.58.163:443/api/course/54e113e8d98e579c1a790bbd/step/54e113e8d98e579c1a790bbe", host: "dev.****.net", referrer: "https://dev.***.net/08f35b9a752554df591279a88babad96fd7e88021084d0396ef7bda16798eaa5743bfc4880015294dd3199482dd9fc564bbf6a681b6881eb5d91b369059a1643"
```

Nginx Configuration under sites-available/default:

```
server {
server_name 10.0.0.134;
listen 80;
root /home/ubuntu/web/portal;

passenger_enabled on;
passenger_set_cgi_param _PASSENGER_NODE_CONTROL_SERVER 1;

location /api {
       access_log off;
       proxy_pass https://dev-api.***.net;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_read_timeout 300;
   }}
```